# HtmlUnit getform() form not found

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I am a Newbie with HtmlUnit .. I want to login on https://trash-mail.com/posteingang/ .

My Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

        HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://www.trash-mail.com/posteingang/");

        HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("inbox-form");
```

I get the following error:

> runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: 'select option:selected' error: Invalid selector: select option:selected).] sourceName=[https://www.trash-mail.com/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js.pagespeed.ce.OXdUuknp4M.js] line=[4] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
>   Exception in thread "main" com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[form] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[inbox-form]
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.getFormByName(HtmlPage.java:647)

Do u have any Idea how this could gonna work?

Regards,
MaddinCoy

It is legal to do this stuff on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On that HTML page, I don't see any form with that name - *inbox-form*. **inbox-form** is the `id` of the form not name.

```
<form id="inbox-form" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off">
```

Either add `name` attribute to form or use one of `getElementById` methods.

This page has only one form so you can try this syntax too `HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);`

**EDIT** - I tried running your code , issue occurs at `HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.trash-mail.com/posteingang/");`

Error Message - `SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: 'select option:selected' error: Invalid selector: select option:selected).] sourceName=[https://www.trash-mail.com/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js.pagespeed.ce.OXdUuknp4M.js] line=[4] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]`

That seems like Jquery support issue of HtmlUnit or some bug in that script or usage , [htmlUnitbugs](http://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1536/)

My advice - 1. don't throw exceptions from main method, try to handle those exceptions 2. debug your each line of code

Doesn't seem we can do much since you can't change that page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If i use 'final HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) page.getElementById("inbox-form");' I get an error... could u please give me a example how to find form and enter something in this form? Thanks...

Comment: what error? try your old code by adding name attribute to form first.

Comment: ` runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: 'select option:selected' error: Invalid selector: select option:selected).] sourceName=[https://www.trash-mail.com/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js.pagespeed.ce.OXdUuknp4M.js] line=[4] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0] `
The Webpage isn't my project cant change code on webserver

Comment: I have revised my answer , try another syntax `HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);`